# Scheme - General question about new types

Tags: scheme

Can we define new types in Scheme such that Scheme will recognize them and
enforce their invariants?

In other words, when I define, for example, ADT for circle (make_circle, get_radious, etc..), I can use it in Scheme as a new type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SRFI-9](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-9/srfi-9.html) defines the define-record-type macro. Most schemes have a variant of define-record, define-struct or something similar which I believe is a simplification of define-record-type.

And then many schemes have some type of CLOS-like object system, such as [tinyclos](http://community.schemewiki.org/?Tiny-CLOS) or Chicken's [Coops](http://wiki.call-cc.org/eggref/4/coops) - both of which implement multimethods, which is quite nice.

Example Using the SRFI-9:

```
(define-record-type circle
    (make-circle r)
    circle?
    (r get-radius))
```

Then in your REPL:

```
>> (define c (make-circle 12))
>> c
#<circle>
>> (get-radius c)
12
>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Racket has powerfull type system. Also `define-struct` is well supported among schemes.